# org.jboss.netty suddenly stops serving

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I am coding a game server using org.jboss.netty. To be honest this is my first time I am coding TCP/IP application.

Netty suddenly stops calling my functions in handler. I tried adding the following lines to kick idle connections:

```
LINE 1 TO PIPELINE :    pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(idleTimer, 82 , 0, 0));

LINES TO HANDLER :   
    public void channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e) throws Exception {
                    super.channelIdle(ctx, e);        
                        ctx.getChannel().close();
                }
```

Still I am facing the same problem.

In this game server, I have timed tasks (have seperate executerthread pool), forexample every 3 seconds it sends message to 1800 clients. Can this be a problem ? Have you ever faced this kind of problem ?

I suppose pushing data to clients periodically may be the problem. Because as we use thread pool in netty , slow connections or bad network may cause long send queues thus effecting available thread count in pool. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you not block the ioworker thread somehow ? I would take some thread-dumps to be sure.

```
jstack <pid>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i didn t know the jstack command. its actually true that somehow working threads were getting blocked. if it happens again jstack will help me figuring out the actual problem.